# How does Swift know the address of an element in an array of Any?

Tags: ios, swift

How does Swift know the address of an element in an array of Any? I can’t find any explanation. For example:

```
var array: [Any] = [0, "1"]
print(array[1]) // print “1”
```

Usually, in other programming languages like C/C++, we can only declare an array of a specified type, therefore we can calculate the address of an element by: `start + index * Element.size`. How to calculate the address of an element of array with a specified index if we don't have a fixed size of elements in the array?

UPDATE:
Apparently I’m not expecting Swift to behave like C. We certainly know how to access an array in Swift. I’m wondering how Swift or other language implements accessing an array of heterogenous types.

Comment: This is _not_ C so why do you expect Swift to behave like C? You access an array by index or by using a for each loop. You can learn a lot about Swift by reading the [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) book

Comment: There are lots of languages that allow arrays of heterogenous types.

Comment: Apparently I’m not expecting Swift to behave like C. We certainly know how to access an array in Swift. I’m wondering how Swift or other language implements accessing an array of heterogenous types. Thanks Paulw, I’m going to search about array heterogeneous types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alejandro Alonso has answered this question in the official Swift forum. FYI:

https://forums.swift.org/t/how-does-swift-know-the-address-of-an-element-in-an-array-of-any/45415/3